# Submitting AJAX form, redirects instead of processing on page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

So when a user accesses my page I have an ajax function that gets the number of rows in a database and spits out the number (works fine). I also have a form where the user can submit a word. What im trying to do is when the user submits a word to the database AJAX will take care of the submit and then run a function to get the new number of rows in the database.

This code redirects to the submit.php page instead of handling it all on the main page

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   display();

   $('.add').on('submit', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
        url: 'submit.php',
        data: $('this').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            display();
        }
        });
    });


});

function display() {
    $(".container").load("ajax.php").hide().delay(500).fadeIn(1500);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"></div>
    <form  action="submit.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="word">
        <input type="submit" class="add" name="add" value="add">
    </form>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test') or die('error could not connect');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM test";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ('error could not query');

        $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        echo '<h1>'.$num.'</h1>';

?>
```

**Submit.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
        //Connect
        $word = $_POST['word'];

        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test') or die('error could not connect');
        $query  = "INSERT INTO test VALUES(0, '$word')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('error could not query');

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should hook the `submit` event up to the `form`, not the submit `button`.

Buttons don't have a submit event, which is why yours isn't being hooked up.

Comment: so i moved the class="add" to the form and took it off the button, it now doesnt redirect to the submit page but it doesnt submit to the db. I can tell that the ajax is working because it calls the display() and fades in the number (but doesnt update??)

Comment: Press F-12, open the NETWORK panel in the debugger and look at what is being said between you and the server. You have a secondary problem, probably on the PHP-side.

Comment: so i changed some of the php, you're right there is an error with some of my error checking... got it to work with just a basic insert query

Answer (score 1):

`$('this').serialize();`

Should be:

`$(this).serialize();`